# Save Bitmap image to internal storage - Permission denied

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

**Solved by adding this code:**

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
```

After going over many posts about this, I'm still not able to solve the error.

Error: Permission Denied. (When saving a photo)

I'm using this code to see if the permission is granted, and it's not granted.

```
int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ClassifierActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
  Toast.makeText(ClassifierActivity.this, "Permission granted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
  Toast.makeText(ClassifierActivity.this, "Permission NOT granted..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I've added this code to the Manifest (and it doesn't work):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved by adding this code:**

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
```